Laravel 11 media library styles.css link incorrect
I have a Laravel 11 app in a docker container that fails to load the styles.css file from Spaite's Media Library Pro.
The URL it calls for is:
Request URL: http://localhost/media-library-pro/styles.css. <- incorrect
The referrer however is correct:
Referrer: http://local.myproject/ <- correct
How do I fix that? All other resources load fine.
In the .env I have: APP_URL=http://local.myproject and that's what I access the project with. I also have the APP_ENV=local set.
I've run:
php artisan config:clear and php artisan config:cache and php artisan storage:link
The output of echo config('app.url'); is: http://local.myproject
The rest of Media library pro works fine, images upload and previews display.
What else can I do or check to see where it's getting http://localhost from?
The controller that outputs the link is:
class MediaLibraryStylesController
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        //        $styles = File::get(__DIR__ . '../resources/js/media-library-pro-styles/dist/styles.css');

        $styles = File::get(__DIR__.'/../../../resources/js/media-library-pro-styles/dist/styles.css');
        $contents = <<<html
                   $styles
            html;

        return response()->make($contents)->header('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    }
}


The styles.css file is in that location.

Ugh. This must've been a view cache issue.
I deleted the @mediaLibraryStyles blade directive, viewed the site, added it back and this time the url was correct.
